# Using POST requests to retrieve tree data in dojo

Tags: dojo, dijit.tree

I'm using dojo 1.4. I'm having a tree component linked to a dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel (actually a subclass of it).

What is the simplest way to make the store use POST requests instead of GETs?

Comment: how you are creating the GET request? can you show us a sample of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Assuming you're using `ItemFileReadStore` for the store. All requests are hardcoded using `dojo.xhrGet`.